# Create react app: script tag url depending on environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

We have a React app created with create-react-app.
We have to include an external script tag in the head tag (in the `public/index.html` file).

The provider of the script provides us 2 snippets: one for development and one for the production environment.

For example, in development environment, the script tag is :

```
<script src="https://myscript.org/scripttemplates/script.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="4a1xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxx-test"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function OptanonWrapper() { }
</script>
```

For production environment, the script tag is:

```
<script src="https://myscript.org/scripttemplates/script.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="4a1xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxx"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function OptanonWrapper() { }
</script>
```

So you can see that the only difference is the `data-domain-script` attribute between the 2 environments.
So my question is, how can we put the good snippet depending of the environment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

in our application we are using this based on `env` variables in our `public/index.html`:

```
    <% if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { %>
    <script src="https://myscript.org/scripttemplates/script.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="4a1xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxx-test"></script>
    <% } else { %>
    <script src="https://myscript.org/scripttemplates/script.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="4a1xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxx"></script>
    <% } %>
```

Node.js will generate classic html based on env variable

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>    
  const x = env === 'prod' ? prodCDN : otherCDN;    
  document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='"+ x + "'><\/scr" + "ipt>");
</script>
```